# Process start & end on button click

Tags: c#-3.0

i have created an application.In that i have created a button.After clicking on the button a process get's started.Now when i press the close('X') button of the application,the application closes.I want all this to happen on a click of a button i.e When i click the button for the first time it should start the process & as soon as click the same button again the process should get closed.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is. Comments are inside code.

```
using System.Diagnostics;

/// <summary>
/// Process started by our app
/// </summary>
Process process;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //  Haven't been started yet or user closed it
    if (process == null || process.HasExited)
    {
        //  Do open
        try
        {
            process = Process.Start("notepad.exe");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //  Inform user about error
        }
    }
    //  It is started
    else
    {
        //  many a thing can go wrong here. 
        //  Even something as simple as user closing the app himself
        try
        {
            //  Send app instruction to close itself
            if (!process.CloseMainWindow())
            {
                //  Unable to comply - has to be put to death
                //  Merciful people might give it a few retries 
                //  before execution
                process.Kill();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //  Inform user about error
        }
        finally
        {
            //  So the cycle of life can start again
            process = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this works well now i open my application on button click and close it through the close button('X') again when i open my application again it requires double button clicks i want this to be done through a single button click please help.

Comment: I've changed my sample. You will find _ || process.HasExited _ part at the beginning of a method.

Comment: I have one more doubt how to close one windows form on the button click

Comment: If you have a reference to other form it is *otherForm.Close();*

Comment: if (process == null || process.HasExited)
if ((s1==null)||(s1.Close())) I wrote this line instead of the above line i am getting the foll error:Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'void'.

Comment: if (s1 != null) { s1.Close(); }

Comment: See declaration of Form.Close() - it does not return a value.

Comment: i have created two forms.Now i want to open the other form on single button click and close the same form on the single button click & again if i click the ('X') button of form the form closes but when i click on the same button the form should open.

Comment: Is there any function to check whether the form has exited or closed, similar to process.HasExited etc...\

Comment: No. You need to subscribe to Closed event of another form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flags that stores a true value if the application is already running i.e. if the button is pressed for the first time. Then use a simple `if` condition to call the respective function.